# counterup the numbers with setInterval (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to counter up the numbers defined in data attribute with set interval.
My code is here.

```
$( ".number" ).each(function(index) {
  var INCREMENT = $(this).data('increment');
  var START_VALUE = 0;
  var count = 0;
  count = INCREMENT;

  $(this).html(count);

  window.setInterval( function(index){
  count += INCREMENT;
      $('.number').html(count);
  }, 1000);
});
```

I'm able to get the numbers initially, but with setInterval, all using the first number in the array.

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/21jqbtv9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line `$('.number').html(count);`

This means it sets all elements with the `number` class equal to the count. You should use `$(this)` instead.

```
$(".number").each(function (index) {
    var currentNum = $(this);
    var INCREMENT = $(this).data('increment');
    var count = 0;
    count = INCREMENT;

    window.setInterval(function (index) {
        count += INCREMENT;
        currentNum.html(count);
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/21jqbtv9/3/

Answer (score 2):

`$('.number').html(count);` will set the innerHTML of all the matching elements.

1. You can use `html()` or `text()` to set the value
2. Convert the value which are retrived from DOM to number using unary `+` operator
3. Update the value for the current element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/21jqbtv9/2/)

```js
function update() {
  // For each of the `.number` element
  $(".number").html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    var increment = +$(this).data('increment') || 0; // Get the increament value and convert it to number or set to 0 if none
    return +oldHTML + increment; // Update the respective element
  });
}

window.setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number" data-increment="2"></div>
<div class="number" data-increment="3"></div>
<div class="number" data-increment="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want:

```
$( ".number" ).each(function(index) {
  var INCREMENT   = $(this).data('increment');
  var START_VALUE = 0;
  var count       = 0;
  count           = INCREMENT;
  var element     = $(this);

  $(this).html(count);

  window.setInterval(function(index){
    count += INCREMENT;
      element.html(count);
  }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/21jqbtv9/4/